# Generate multiple plots with for loop; display output in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, batch-processing, subplot

**Objective**: To generate 100 barplots using a for loop, and display the output as a subplot image

**Data format**: Datafile with 101 columns. The last column is the X variable; the remaining 100 columns are the Y variables, against which x is plotted.

**Desired output**: Barplots in 5 x 20 subplot array, as in this example image: [image: Subplot - 3 x 2 array example]

**Current approach**: I've been using PairGrid in seaborn, which generates an n x 1 array: [image: example output].

where input == dataframe; input3 == list from which column headers are called:

```
for i in input3:
    plt.figure(i)
    g = sns.PairGrid(input,
             x_vars=["key_variable"],
             y_vars=i,
             aspect=.75, size=3.5)
    g.map(sns.barplot, palette="pastel")
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

To give an example of how to plot 100 dataframe columns over a grid of 20 x 5 subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(3,101)
data[:,0] = np.arange(2,7,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=20, figsize=(21,9), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.bar(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,i+1])
    ax.set_xticks(df.iloc[:,0])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use matplotlob's [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to create the plot grid and pass the axis to the [barplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html). The axis indexing you could do using a nested loop...